Fujitsu Lifebook T935 Touchpad Not Working on Ubuntu, But Works on Windows
Issue:
I'm encountering an issue with my Fujitsu Lifebook T935 laptop where the touchpad does not work on Ubuntu, although it functions perfectly on Windows. Interestingly, the touchpad works on other brands like Dell and HP when running Ubuntu.
Laptop Specifications:
Model: Fujitsu Lifebook T935
Operating System: Ubuntu 24.04LTS
Kernel Version: 6.8.0-38-generic
Touchpad: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
Checked Input Devices:
    Used libinput debug-events --enable-tap and found that only touchscreen events are detected, not the touchpad.
    Output example:

    go

-event7   DEVICE_ADDED            Fujitsu FUJ02E3                   seat0 default group1  cap:k
-event9   DEVICE_ADDED            Video Bus                         seat0 default group2  cap:k
-event8   DEVICE_ADDED            Fujitsu FUJ02BF                   seat0 default group3  cap:kS
-event1   DEVICE_ADDED            Power Button                      seat0 default group4  cap:k
-event0   DEVICE_ADDED            Lid Switch                        seat0 default group5  cap:S
-event2   DEVICE_ADDED            Sleep Button                      seat0 default group6  cap:k
-event5   DEVICE_ADDED            Wacom MultiTouch Sensor Finger    seat0 default group7  cap:t  size 294x165mm ntouches 10 calib
-event6   DEVICE_ADDED            Wacom MultiTouch Sensor Pen       seat0 default group7  cap:T  size 296x167mm left calib
-event3   DEVICE_ADDED            AT Translated Set 2 keyboard      seat0 default group8  cap:k
-event4   DEVICE_ADDED            SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad        seat0 default group9  cap:pg  size 110x71mm tap(dl off) left scroll-nat scroll-2fg-edge click-buttonareas-clickfinger dwt-on dwtp-on

Loaded Kernel Modules:
Tried loading i2c_hid and i2c_hid_acpi modules.

bash
sudo modprobe i2c_hid
sudo modprobe i2c_hid_acpi
Updated Kernel:
Ensured my kernel is up to date using:

bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install linux-generic
Adjusted Touchpad Settings:
Used xinput to list and adjust touchpad properties.

bash
xinput list
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "libinput Tapping Enabled" 1
Installed Synaptics Driver:
Switched from libinput to xserver-xorg-input-synaptics driver.

bash
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

Checked for Firmware Updates:
    Ensured my laptop firmware is up to date from Fujitsu's support site.

Different Ubuntu Versions:
    Tried different versions of Ubuntu to see if the issue persists across them.

Detailed Analysis:
After performing the above steps, the touchpad still doesn't respond in Ubuntu.
Only touchscreen events are being detected, as observed from the libinput debug events output.

Request for Help:
I'm seeking guidance on any further steps I can take to resolve this touchpad issue. Has anyone experienced a similar problem with Fujitsu laptops or have any additional suggestions for troubleshooting? Your help would be greatly appreciated!
Sources:
Ubuntu Forums
Fujitsu Support Forum
Ask Ubuntu

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Mostly an FYI, but you specify you're using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS but don't say if you're using the Desktop or Server version. By installing linux-generic which in included only on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Server installs, are you saying Server?  as Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop uses linux-generic-hwe-24.04 as you'll see listed in the manifest file for Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop ISOs (https://releases.ubuntu.com/24.04/ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.manifest)   ie. you may have two kernel stacks now installed on your system (GA + HWE), so was this an intention (if Desktop) or are you using 24.04 LTS Server?
